# mysqli_fetch_array does not know the return value of join select statement mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on data base system which i need to return the values from data base and out put them in a table form and i use join statement when i am trying to run the web page it comes up with this error message:

> Notice: Undefined index: student.name in ...

Here is part of my code

```
   if (isset($_POST['submit_exam'])){
        $gerayesh_id=mysqli_real_escape_string($cnn,$_POST['gerayesh_id']);
        $exam_number=mysqli_real_escape_string($cnn,$_POST['exam_number']);
        $query="SELECT student.name , student.lname , student.student_id , exam.exam_number , exam.exam_id FROM";
        $query.=" exam  JOIN exam_register  on exam.exam_id=exam_register.exam_id";
        $query.=" JOIN student  on student.student_id=exam_register.student_id";
        $query.=" WHERE (exam.gerayesh_id=$gerayesh_id)";
        $query.=" AND (exam.exam_number=$exam_number)";
        $result=mysqli_query($cnn,$query);
        if($result){
        echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"manage_add_result.php\"  target=\"_blank\" style=\"float:right;\">";
    echo "<table >";
        echo    "<tr>";
                echo "<th>&#1606;&#1575;&#1605;</th>";
                echo "<th>&#1606;&#1575;&#1605; &#1582;&#1608;&#1575;&#1606;&#1608;&#1575;&#1583;&#1711;&#1740;</th>";
                echo"<th>&#1588;&#1605;&#1575;&#1585;&#1607; &#1570;&#1586;&#1605;&#1608;&#1606;</th>";
                echo "<th>&#1575;&#1606;&#1578;&#1582;&#1575;&#1576;</th>";


            echo"</tr>";
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){

            echo"<tr>";
            echo"<td>{$row['student.name']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$row['student.lname']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$row['exam.exam_number']}</td>";
            echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" value=\" {$row['student.student_id']}\" name=\"student_id\"/></td>";
            echo "<input type=hidden name=exam_id value=\"{$row['exam.exam_id']}\">";


            echo"</tr>";        

     }
    // $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

     echo"</table>";
         echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit_student\" value=\"&#1570;&#1662;&#1604;&#1608;&#1583; &#1705;&#1575;&#1585;&#1606;&#1575;&#1605;&#1607;;\">";
     echo "</form>";



        } else{echo mysqli_error($cnn);}


    }
```

the error undefined index shows for all of my variables that should be shown in table 
i am wondering what can i do 
thanks for your time

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: in result you will have data on keys as the name of columns(not with table names) from your query like `$row['name'], student is a table name and referenced in select statement to pick the name  column from students table

Comment: `['name']` not `['student.name']` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys in the associative array are just the column names, not `table.column`. So use:

```
        echo"<td>{$row['name']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$row['lname']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$row['exam_number']}</td>";
        echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" value=\" {$row['student_id']}\" name=\"student_id\"/></td>";
        echo "<input type=hidden name=exam_id value=\"{$row['exam_id']}\">";
```

If you return columns from different tables that have the same name, you'll need to give them aliases to be able to reference both of them. This isn't an issue with your query, where all the column names in the `SELECT` clause are different.